# How to get the stacktrace of OpenCL kernel compiler?

Tags: java, opencl, lwjgl

When I call `CL10.clBuildProgram(program, devices.get(0), "", null)` method it throws `org.lwjgl.opencl.OpenCLException: Error Code: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE (0xFFFFFFF5)` exception. Everything I know that it's a build failure, but I don't get any clarification of my mistake in my kernel code.

How to get the staktrace of kernel compiler after such error?

Comment: Maybe showing the kernel you are compiling might help...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I fix my code every time I meet such problem, but it takes a lot of time and significant attention to find the error cause. I would like to have a common approach to such problems.

Comment: Note: OpenCL error codes are signed, not unsigned. In other words, CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE is -11, not 0xFFFFFFF5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the build log by calling `clGetProgramBuildInfo` with `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG`.

In LWJGL, there is a convenience method for this:

```
...
clBuildProgram(program, devices.get(0), "", null);
System.out.println(program.getBuildInfoString(
    devices.get(0), CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG));
```

This will print any error messages that result from building the program.

---

> The remaining part is mainly from before editing this answer:

For a different Java OpenCL binding, namely for JOCL from jocl.org, I created this utility method. It is part of the `CL` class. Then `CL.setExceptionsEnabled(true)` was called, this method will be called internally if the build of a program fails, and its output will be part of the exception message. It shows the basic process of how the program log may be obtained, so I'll leave it here for reference.

```
/**
 * Obtain a single String containing the build logs of the given program for
 * all devices that are associated with the given program object.
 *
 * @param program The program object
 * @return The build logs, as a single string.
 */
private static String obtainBuildLogs(cl_program program)
{
    int numDevices[] = new int[1];
    CL.clGetProgramInfo(program, CL.CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, Sizeof.cl_uint, Pointer.to(numDevices), null);
    cl_device_id devices[] = new cl_device_id[numDevices[0]];
    CL.clGetProgramInfo(program, CL.CL_PROGRAM_DEVICES, numDevices[0] * Sizeof.cl_device_id, Pointer.to(devices), null);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i<devices.length; i++)
    {
        sb.append("Build log for device "+i+":\n");
        long logSize[] = new long[1];
        CL.clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[i], CL.CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, null, logSize);
        byte logData[] = new byte[(int)logSize[0]];
        CL.clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[i], CL.CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, logSize[0], Pointer.to(logData), null);
        sb.append(new String(logData, 0, logData.length-1));
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yep, I guess it's exactly what I need. Please, port this to the LWJGL version.

Comment: @PavelRyzhov I can't do this now (old PC), but will do it tomorrow evening, edit the answer accordingly, and drop you a note (sorry for the delay)

Comment: That's fine, thanks for the notice,  I've found a typo in my kernel code, but the question is still actual.

Comment: @PavelRyzhov I just edited the answer. In the end, it's a one-liner, because there is a convenience method for this in LWJGL.